# How to split words that are connected together in java？

Tags: java, solr

For example：`HelloWorld`

Expect：`Hello World`

I tried to use Solr's tokenizer, but did not find a suitable tokenizer to do this.
What should I do?

Comment: not case sensitive

Comment: if its not case sensitive, you would literally have nothing to delimit the words/tokens in the string. You could probably use indexes to extract substrings and compare against a dictionary of valid words, however, that would depend on how extensive your dictionary is.

Comment: but then again, how would you know when to stop? he is a valid word. hell is a valid word. hello is a valid word. low is a valid word.

Comment: So you need to exhaust all the possibilities. The best case is that the given string can just be split into complete words. I think this is related to machine learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DictionaryCompoundWordFilter is built for this in Solr](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/language-analysis.html#dictionary-compound-word-token-filter); it's not a tokenizer, but it works as a filter after the tokenizer to split known words from a substring into separate tokens. This is in particular useful in many other languages than English, but have value here as well.

You give it a dictionary of valid words in your language of choice (in your example, these would be `hello` and `world` ), and the filter extracts these to separate tokens:

> Assume that germanwords.txt contains at least the following words: `dumm kopf donau dampf schiff`
>
> ```
> <analyzer>
>   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
>   <filter class="solr.DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory" dictionary="germanwords.txt"/>
> </analyzer>
> ```
>
> In: `"Donaudampfschiff dummkopf"`
>
> Tokenizer to Filter: `"Donaudampfschiff"(1), "dummkopf"(2),`
>
> Out: `"Donaudampfschiff"(1), "Donau"(1), "dampf"(1), "schiff"(1), "dummkopf"(2), "dumm"(2), "kopf"(2)`

Answer (score 1):

If the tokenizer accepts regular expressions, you could use the following pattern as the token:

```regex
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Sample Java code:

```java
String input = "HelloWorld";
String[] words = input.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));  // [Hello, World]
```

Comment: If this is the case 'helloworld' not 'HelloWorld',Can I still use regular expressions？

Comment: @stone You can't use this particular regex in my answer.  But maybe there might be some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
String.split(condition);
```

Example:

```
String words = "HelloWorldHi";
words.split("regex"); // This will give you an array of words ["Hello", "World", "Hi"]
```

Example regex: [RegExr Example](http://regexr.com/63rkb)

```
[A-Z][a-z]{1,}
```

Breakdown:

```
[A-Z]: Match any character in the set (From A to Z)
[a-z]: Match any character in the set. From (a to z)
{1, }: Matches the specified quantity of the previous token. {1,3} will match 1 to 3. {3} will match exactly 3. {1,} will match 1 or more.
```

Comment: It doesn't work if i use helloworld

Comment: It doesn't work regardless

Comment: Check this DevilsHnd: regexr.com/63rkb, and stone nope you might need to see another regex.